# OLE: Shared IStorage for multiple OLE objects?

Tags: c++, com, powerpoint, ole

I am currently implementing an `IOleObject` interface to embed visualized data of our software into other software like PowerPoint. Our software creates graphical evaluations of measured data (diagrams, etc).

The goal is, that the end-user can make a double click on the embedded OLE object to edit it in our software. The data will be stored using the given `IStorage` interface in `IPersistStorage::Save/Load`. The measured data must be embedded, not linked.

My current solution works fine, but the problem is, that the embedded data will be saved once per OLE object. In example we have got 10 MB of measured data and the end-user embeds fifty different diagrams of that measured data into PowerPoint, the measured data will be embedded fifty times in the PowerPoint file (50 * 10 MB = 500 MB, although 10 MB per PowerPoint file would be enough).

**My question is if there exists any shared IStorage interface for the entire container(?) or something similiar?**

The given IStorage interfaces in IPersistStorage::Load/Save depends only on the specific, embedded OLE object.

It would be great if I could tell the host application something like "PowerPoint, my fifty OLE objects share that IStorage there. Please save it only once in the PPTX file".

Comment: Could you share some example or documentation about how to implement it (which works)? I'm having error with PowerPoint because it doesn't call my `IPersistStorage::Save/Load` methods.

Comment: I'm not sure what is exactly required that PowerPoint calls your methods.
My interface listens to the following IIDs:
- IOleObject = IID_IUnknown, IID_IOleObject
- IDataObject = IID_IDataObject
- IPersistStorage = IID_IPersist, IID_IPersistStorage
- IDispatch = IID_IDispatch

Maybe you aren't handling the Close method correctly (you must call ClientSite->SaveObject() if the flags specify saving). And you must handle the list of AdviseSinks in your object and inform these sinks about specific events (i. e. OnClose).

Maybe you are missing one of these actions.

Comment: Exactly, I was missing some of these actions. Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that's the way OLE embedding is supposed to work.  Each object gets its own storage in the container.  If it's the same object with the same data, why does it need to be embedded 50 times?  If it's the same object and you want it to be be on different pages in the presentation, why not embed the first instance and make all the remaining instances links?  That would save storage.  Of course, if you delete the first embedded instance, all the links will turn to ....

Comment: On each embedded object a different diagram is shown. The measured data for the object is the same, but the settings for the diagram are different.
I had already thought about such a solution, but how should I link the other OLE objects to the first (embedded) OLE object?

Comment: If you are going to have different presentations, then you are going to probably need different embedded objects.  I would probably do something like have 2 types of objects.  One, is the object that has your data store which of course is embedded.  Then you would have a different type of object that is your presentation.  It could be much smaller, but it would need to be initialized with something like a moniker to your data store object so that it could retrieve data for presentation.

Comment: Ok, I will try that as an additional option. Thanks.

Comment: One more comment... Sometimes there isn't even a global storage for the file.  For instance, consider WordPad or anything else using the RICHEDIT control.  The RTF format is a text format, but it can contain embedded objects.  The RICHEDIT control has an IRichEditOleCallback which has a GetNewStorage() member for creating the storage for an embedded OLE object.  Some people might implement using StgCreateDocfileOnILockBytes() from an ILockBytes created from CreateILockBytesOnHGlobal()--and many do...Look up COleClientItem::GetItemStorageFlat() in MFC source.  Wordpad uses it.